# Prevent CSS animation when javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there some CSS that I can add inside a `<noscript>` that will prevent animations on a certain element when scripts are disabled?

In other words, I want to prevent CSS3 animations on a certain class when scripts are disabled.

Comment: Or you could add the CSS file containing animations when scripts are enabled ;) `head appendChild`

Answer (score 7):

What you *can* do is set a class when JavaScript is *enabled*. Make sure all the animations look at that class.

Answer (score 0):

With JS you can add a class to your body tag, something like .js-enabled; in your css scope the animations with that specific class.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem recently. The easiest way is to assign a class *on load*. That is your initial state then, and the state you want something to transition to is either the state without the class (when, for example, you want to reveal stuff) or yet another class. Or, if you're using a looped animation, then of course you don't have to worry about that and just assign animations to a class.